# Restricting access to static files in Django/Nginx

Tags: django, security, nginx

I am building a system that allows users to generate a documents and then download them. The documents are PDFs (not that it matters for the sake of this question) and when they are generated I store them on my local file system that the web server is running on with uuid file names

c7d43358-7532-4812-b828-b10b26694f0f.pdf

but I know "security through obscurity" is not the right solution ...

I want to restrict access to they files on a per account basis if possible. One thing I think I could do is upload them to S3 and provide a signed URL, but I want to avoid that for now if possible.

I am using Nginx/Django/Gunicorn/EC2/S3

What are some other solutions?

Comment: For me [django-private-storage](https://github.com/edoburu/django-private-storage) have done the magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about enforcing `user==owner` at the view level, preventing access to the files, storing them as FileFields, and only retrieving the file if that condition is met.

e.g. You could use the `@login_required` [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) on the view to allow access only if logged in. This could be refined using `request.user` to check against the owner of the file. The User Auth section of the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) is likely to be helpful here.

The other option, as you mention is via S3 itself, generating urls within Django which have a querystring allowing an authenticated user access to download a particular s3 object with a time limit. Details on that can be found at the [s3 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth?r=4303). A similar question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7923972/781909) on SO.

Answer (score 10):

If you are serving small files, you can indeed use Django to serve them directly, writing the file into the `HttpResponse`  object.

If you're serving large files however, you might want to leave that task to your webserver, you can use the `X-Accel-Redirect` header on Nginx (and `X-Sendfile` for Apache & Lighttpd) to have your webserver serve the file for you.

You can find more information about the header itself [in Nginx's documentation here](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile), and you could find [some inspiration as to how to use that in Django here](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile).

Once you're done sending files through Django views, enforcing user authentication should be pretty straightfoward using Django's auth framework.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [django-private-files](https://bitbucket.org/vvangelovski/django-private-files/src) with great success, it enforces protection at the view level and uses differente backends to do the actual file transfer.